# CRM-like system using drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, blogs, crm

I have a website running in drupal. Is there a module or some way to build a functionality which essentially builds a crm-like system on top of drupal?
I want to basically support this,
1. Create some kind of ticketing system that keys on each user
2. A blog like interface where various customer service personnel can make comments - again keyed by userid
3. A decent interface where you can list comments etc by date
4. Possibly another page to search for entries with certain keywords.
5. Support additional customization on top.

If the above is not possible is there a easy way to embed a third party crm application in drupal to provide the above?

Thanks,
Vivek

Answer (score 0):

You might like to check out [Open Atrium](http://openatrium.com/). It is a customized Drupal distribution by Phase2 Tech. Though its an out-of-the-box solution for ticketing system, you can modify it to your needs just like any Drupal installation.

Another open source solution could be [CiviCRM](http://civicrm.org/). It won't serve as OOB solution but provides plenty of UI configurable options to fit your needs. Its a bit complex to start but once configured well, its quite powerful system. It integrates with Joomla and Drupal.